# How to remove child nodes of selected node in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I am facing difficulty in deleting child nodes of a selected node.

```
$(function () {
$("#tree").jstree({ 
    "json_data" : {
        "data" : [
            { 
                data : "/", 
                attr : { "id" : "root"},
                state : "closed",
                "children" : [ { "data" : "child1",
                                "attr" : { "id" : "child1.id" },
                                "children" : [ ] }
                             ]
            },
        ]
    },
    "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "crrm", "ui" ]
})
```

I am using $("#tree").jstree("remove", data.rslt.obj); to remove the child nodes below the node itself but it also deletes the node selected. How can I delete the just child nodes of a selected node and not the selected node ?

Comment: You're going to want to get the children and then call the remove method on each one unless the remove function can handle an array of nodes. Unfortunately, jstree is an old project that hasn't had any love for a long time. Check out the DHTML tree if you need something that has a cleaner API and better support. http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxTree/index.shtml

Comment: I understand the procedure but looking for its implementation. Unfortunately the project I am working on has been already implemented in jstree so I want to make a few modifications to solve the purpose instead of changing the API altogether. Anyways, thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Redtopia correctly pointed out, jsTree does not have the cleanest API.

Unfortunately, I believe that the solution will have to be something like:

```
$("#tree").jstree("remove",data.rslt.obj.find('li'));
```

Comment: I too agree with @REdTtopia. Thanks to you both for help. I appreciate