# Remove child nodes and redraw jstree inside selected node

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I have used jstree to bind the data inside it.

But whenever I open the node I mean expand the node it overwrite the existing with double time binding I have tried following FAQ but not getting the solution.

[Remove Child Nodes](http://javascript.qahowto.com/How-to-remove-child-nodes-of-selected-node-in-jstree-javascript-jquery-jstree-11fce56)

[Remove Child nodes (SOF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18861654/how-to-remove-child-nodes-of-selected-node-in-jstree)

I have also tried the following code it removes in debugging but it binds again double time.

```
$("#" + $("#jstree").jstree("get_selected")).find('li').remove();
```

[Sample code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxWD5dDW0892MTlBR0V5cFRFVW8)

Comment: I have same issue....i dont get solution yet